# Box-shadow overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an inset shadow on two elements and overlay them so they look like well with tab. Everything looks great except for one corner where I cannot figure out how to make it look smooth. (highlighted with yellow). 
[image]

[**JsFiddle for test**](http://jsfiddle.net/pRX7A/)
this is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outerWell">
    <div class="well" style="padding-top:15px">
        text
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well" style="margin-top:40px">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

and then I have css that creates shadow and hides one side of shadow with `overflow:hidden`
*(.well class is taken from bootstrap)*

```
 .well {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 1px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 1px #888;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 1px #888;
    }
        .outerWell {
        width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    position:absolute;
        }
```

Is there an easy way to fix my issue, or maybe a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I usually add a border-radius on that corner and get it lined up as perfectly as I can.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, the problem is that that corner is not really a corner, since I'm using overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably pull this off with some creative use of pseudo elements. Have a look at [this post on CSS-Tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/better-tabs-with-round-out-borders/)